# wrong tracking code for Google Analytics?

Tags: google-analytics

I use Magento 1.9.1.0. I enabled the Google API under System - Configuration - SALES - Google API by entering the Account Number. I have 2 stores (2 different domains selling different products).

Now - I get the following in my Google Analytics:

In Google Analytics under Reporting it says:

> ! Destination URLs Not Tagged
>
> Tracking Code Mismatch Destination URL www.thedomain.com/ is tagged
>   with tracking code for the wrong property.

I use the same Google Account number for both stores (domains). Is this the problem or what needs to be done to resolve this? Thanks for any suggestions! ;-)

Comment: In your google analytics account, do you have a different code for each domain name?

Comment: How do I find that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please use Google Code one time.
To track different stores set 2 Analytic-Codes.
CMS > SYSTEM > Current Configuration Scope > CHOOSE YOUR STORE and setup the Code for every store.